# About the tangent of a rational multiple of $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

During extra classes we got an interesting problem (as a homework)

> Decide if there is a rational number alpha such that
>   $$\tan (\alpha\pi) = \sqrt{7}$$

I have tried to solve this, using complex numbers, but it's gone wrong. If anyone has any idea, please let me know.
Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. If $\alpha=p/q$ then 
$$(\cos(\alpha \pi) + i\sin(\alpha \pi))^{2q}=e^{2\pi pi}=1\quad
\mbox{and}\quad(\cos (\alpha \pi) - i\sin (\alpha \pi))^{2q}=e^{-2\pi p i}=1$$
which means that $(\cos(\alpha \pi) \pm i\sin(\alpha \pi))$ are [algebraic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer). Hence also their sum, that is $2\cos(\alpha \pi)$, is an algebraic integer.

If $\tan (\alpha\pi) = \sqrt{7}$ what are the possible  values of $2\cos(\alpha \pi)$?

P.S. Recall that  the sum, difference and product of two algebraic integers is an algebraic integer. If a number is an algebraic integer and a rational number then it is an integer.